# How to find rhombus of the same char in 2D Char Array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, geometry, boolean

let's say that I have a code that has a 2d char  array (max of 12*12),
and I want to find in the array sequence of chars that make rhombus, how can I do it? I thought about making a boolean function that checks each place if it has the same values as his neighbors and other functions that use it to find rhombus but I don't really know how to use it.

At the end of this, I want to print the rhombus center values and the char that makes the rhombus.

thk

another thing, I cant use recursion.
[Example of rhombus in 2d array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpXsf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach:

Make four 2d integer arrays of the same size or one 2d array of arrays[0..3].

Walk through all diagonals in four directions, incrementing corresponding entries of auxiliary arrays if neighbors are similar. For example, walking from top "F" in bottom-right direction, put 0, 1 and 2 into `UPLEFT[1][2], UPLEFT[2][3]` and `UPLEFT[3][4]` correspondingly. Instead of diagonal walking, you can traverse line-by line twice - from the top, and from the bottom, checking needed upper neighbors during forward scan, and bottom neighbors during bottom-up scan.

Now scan array again. When you have index pair `[k][m]` with `UPRIGHT[k][m]>0` and `DOWNRIGHT[k][m]>0`, choose minimal value

```
Wdt = min(UPRIGHT[k][m], DOWNRIGHT[k][m])
```

and check `UPLEFT[k][r]` and `DOWNLEFT[k][r]` for values `r = m + 2*Wdt downto m+2` to reveal **the largest rhombus with left corner** in `[k][m]` pair.

Comment: @Swanky_Dwarf Is my answer unclear?